# Quick Solidworks question: How to cut a 3D part along a line in a sketch?

Tags: solidworks

I'm not having luck with the Trim Entities feature, which is just for sketches. I just want to shave the top part off completely at the angle that I've drawn.
[image]

Comment: Make your angle into a plane along face you want to cut, then you can use it to trim or cut.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat thank you! that worked (with insert > cut > with surface)

Comment: In Solidworks, there are many ways to do things.

Comment: @Mohanachz - if "that worked" how come still no answer is marked correct? 

Comment: @JonathanRSwift oops sorry, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this - I've illustrated both @StainlessSteelRat's Plane Cut method, and @NMech's Cut/Extrude method.

Both are valid, and as always with these questions - there's not enough context to recommend which of these two, or the numerous other potential methods is best for your situation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Just create a sketch on that face.
- Then draw a box that includes completely the part you want to get rid off.
- Use that sketch with a cut extrude feature.